# Unable to login in magento admin panel in any browser

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie, aws, loadbalancing, cloudfront-cdn

I am unable to login in magento admin panel. Magento ver. 1.9.2.4. Reason is in every minute its calling this:

Error : {ajaxExpired: 1,…}
ajaxExpired
:
1
ajaxRedirect
:    "https://www.gleitsichtbrille.de/index.php/ag_supervista/index/login/key/dc32322811d123b75356a152194991d0/"

I have followed below steps to solve this error:

1. Clear browser cache, history,etc
2. Delete cache folder from var.
3. checked with below code to comment it in `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php` and remove cache:

   ```
   // session cookie params
   /*$cookieParams = array(
       'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
       'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
       'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
       'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
       'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
   );*/
   ```
4. Set Permission 777 to cache and session folder.
5. Set web configuration "Use HTTP Only" to "No".

Comment: Site is in aws. If we remove load balancer then it is working fine.

Comment: Is your customer accounts working as expected? customers are able to login and browse with in their account?

Comment: There is no myaccount option in the site.This site CMS only. Frontend site is working fine. There is an issue wit admin panel only.

Comment: Everything else working? add to cart checkout etc?

Comment: This site CMS only. Frontend site is working fine. There is an issue with admin panel only. Once login its now redirecting to black page. If I enter manually in the url, page is loading. It is not working when click event is fire.

Comment: Check your server/magento error logs

Comment: No error is showing in log.

Comment: On every click admin panel is redirecting to HTTP ERROR 500. Once I refresh the page it is working. Only click event is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is solved now!!!

I have deleted Application Load Balancer from AWS EC2 and followed below steps to create Classic Load Balancer with cookies 3600 as same was in my magento site.

- Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
- On the navigation pane, under LOAD BALANCING, choose Target Groups.
- Select the target group.
- On the Description tab, choose Edit attributes.
- On the Edit attributes page, do the following:
- Select Enable load balancer generated cookie stickiness.
- For Stickiness duration, specify a value between 1 second and 7 days.
- Choose Save.